# Password generator like pwgen on Windows (cmd)

Tags: windows

I'm looking for handy password generator for Windows enviroment. I have found pwgen. Is this possible to generate password in Windows cmd with pwgen?

Comment: Please also see https://superuser.com/a/1333853/1813176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bitwarden CLI](https://bitwarden.com/help/cli/), for instance:

```
bw generate --length 20
```

Check all available options [here](https://bitwarden.com/help/cli/#generate).

Comment: Thank you Poland!